# How do i align my layout like this in landscape mode?

Tags: android, layout

I know title is bad but i dont know how to explain this with words.I want my layout to align like below picture on landscape mode.

Example:

[image]

With my code insert new task part goes below to tasks list not near to it as in picture

my code:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Tasks:"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/tasks"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Add new task:"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Desc"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addtask"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Add Task"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/desc" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks for your help i cant add more details since i think images explain better

Comment: Create two different XML files, one for design in portrait mode and other for landscape mode.

Comment: This is why you should post code, not images of code. The images are no longer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two different XML files, one for design in portrait mode and other for landscape mode.   Put in `layout-port` and `layout-land` folder inside `res` folder.

Example:

```
res/layout-port [Portrait Mode; default]
main.xml
res/layout-land [Landscape Mode]
main1.xml
```

Reference Documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a new layout xml file for the landscape mode and put it into the layout-land directory.

More info here (under Add orientation qualifiers) https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#alternative-layouts